# Performance of Views in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, view

How does SQL Server handle updates on views. I am worried about performance and wanted to know overview of how and when views change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [non-materialized] view is just a stored query that gets run when you use the view name in a query.

Performance for a [non-materialized] view comes from the query getting cached, because the view's underlying query doesn't change.  Once the view query is altered, the first time will take a little longer than subsequent ones because there's nothing in the query cache.

You can use [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx), but have I have experienced locking (even within a READUNCOMMITTED transaction).

Materialized ("indexed" in TSQL/SQL Server) views are a different matter.